# Value from redux is different inside component body then in the return function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, openai-api

I am trying to get the latest value of history from redux store to pass in a payload. The issue is whenever I submit a query, the history is getting updated and looping with map() inside return() it is showing the latest value but at // CONSOLE HERE inside submitQuery() it is keep showing old values.

```
export default function Chat() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { customInstructionId, chatId } = useParams()
  const { history } = useSelector((state) => state.customData)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmitQuery = async () => {
    if(!query || query === "" || query === null) {
      return notification("Query can't be empty.",  "error")
    }
    setLoading(true)
    const data = { id: Math.random(), role: 'user', content: query }
    setQuery("")
    dispatch(addData(data))
    const config = { query: [...history, data], key: customInstructionId }
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/query/chat", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(config),
      });
      if (!response.ok || !response.body) {
        throw response.statusText;
      }
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      const loopRunner = true;
      let str = ""
      let count = 0
      const resId = Math.random()
      setLoading(false);
      /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
      while (loopRunner) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            // CONSOLE HERE
          handleSaveHistory()
          break;
        }
        const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
        if(value[0] === 10){
          str += "\n"
        } else {
          str += decodedChunk
        }
        if(count === 0){
          dispatch(addData({ id: resId, role: 'assistant', content: str }))
        } else {
          dispatch(updateData({ id: resId, content: str }))
        }
        count += 1
      }
      // CONSOLE HERE
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err, "err");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  const handleSaveHistory = async () => {
    // CONSOLE HERE
    const config = saveHistory({ history, customInstructionId, chatId }, token)
    axios(config)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      notification(`Unable to save the history.`, "error")
    })
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        handleSubmitQuery();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Page title="Query" sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <Container sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between', height: '100%' }}>
          <Box sx={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: '70vh'}}>
            {(history && history.length > 0) ? history.map((item) =>
              <Card key={item.id} sx={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>
                <Typography sx={{ padding: '1rem', backgroundColor: item.role === 'user' ? '#f8eff0' : '#edeff1' }}>
                  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') }} />
                </Typography>
              </Card>
            ) : 
            <Card sx={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>
              <Typography sx={{ padding: '1rem', backgroundColor: '#edeff1' }}>Hi! How can I assist you today?</Typography>
            </Card>
            }
            {loading && loading === true &&
            <Card sx={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>
              <Typography sx={{ padding: '1rem', backgroundColor: '#edeff1' }}>
                <Skeleton variant="text" sx={{ fontSize: '1rem' }} />
              </Typography>
            </Card>
            }
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

Redux Store:

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "customData",
  initialState: {
    history: [],
    boolean: true,
    string: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    addData: (state, action) => {
      state.history.push(action.payload)
    },
    updateData: (state, action) => {
      state.history = state.history.map(data => {
        if (data.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...data,
            content: action.payload.content
          };
        }
        return data;
      });
    },
    removeData: (state, action) => {
      state.history = state.history.filter(data => data.id !== action.payload)
    },
    recentData: (state, action) => {
      state.history = action.payload
    },
    clearData: (state) => {
      state.history = []
    }
  }
});

export const { addData, updateData, removeData, clearData, recentData } = counterSlice.actions;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Note: It is not the whole code, just showing the context of the issue. If anyone know why is this occuring.

In the below image, history is indeed getting updating with dispatch(), and I am able to see it in the UI (it is coming word by word just like in chatgpt). when the whole response has finished then I am executing the saveHistory function, but in that function it is not taking the most recent question/answer.

[image]

History(in UI):

1. abc
2. def
3. ghi
4. jkl

History(in saveHistory func):

1. abc
2. def

**UPDATE:**
The issue is when I call save func inside handleSubmit func. below solved the issue but I know it is not a good practice.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(ready === true) {
      handleSaveHistory()
      setReady(false)
    }
  }, [ready]);
```

Comment: try to use useEffect to update your component when history changes: You can use the useEffect hook to execute specific code whenever the history state changes.

Comment: thats not the question. why history is giving latest value in return() but no the submit function? and usong useEffect wont be a good practice.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what *specifically* is the issue or problem you face, in better detail, include what the expected logged value should be versus what is observed. See [mcve].

Comment: Does `dispatch(addData(data))` update the value of `history`?

Comment: Check out my explanation below. With information about `addData` and what `history` is in your store I can offer a solution.

Comment: updated @RossAllen

Comment: Your action is quite complex, and it should be written using [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). Move anything async out of the component and follow the guide in Redux's docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async work needs to be done outside the component using [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). The following should go in your Redux store:

```js
const handleSaveHistory = createAsyncThunk(
  'customData/handleSaveHistory',
  async (customInstructionId, chatId, thunkAPI) => {
    // CONSOLE HERE
    const config = thunkAPI.dispatch(saveHistory({
      history: thunkAPI.getState().history,
      customInstructionId,
      chatId,
    }, token))
    axios(config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        notification(`Unable to save the history.`, "error")
      })
  } 
);

const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'customData/handleSubmitQuery',
  async (query, customInstructionId, chatId, thunkAPI) => {
    if(!query || query === "" || query === null) {
      return notification("Query can't be empty.",  "error")
    }
    const data = { id: Math.random(), role: 'user', content: query }
    thunkAPI.dispatch(addData(data))
    const config = { query: [...history, data], key: customInstructionId }
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/query/chat", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(config),
      });
      if (!response.ok || !response.body) {
        throw response.statusText;
      }
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      const loopRunner = true;
      let str = ""
      let count = 0
      const resId = Math.random()
      /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
      while (loopRunner) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
            // CONSOLE HERE
          thunkAPI.dispatch(handleSaveHistory(customInstructionId, chatId))
          break;
        }
        const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
        if(value[0] === 10){
          str += "\n"
        } else {
          str += decodedChunk
        }
        if(count === 0){
          thunkAPI.dispatch(addData({ id: resId, role: 'assistant', content: str }))
        } else {
          thunkAPI.dispatch(updateData({ id: resId, content: str }))
        }
        count += 1
      }
      // CONSOLE HERE
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err, "err");
    }
  }
)
```

The issue is your hook `handleSaveHistory` function closed over an old version of the data. You have `async` functions that are executing in a previously-rendered version of your component.

initial state:

```
Chat1 (visible to user)
 - history1
 - handleSubmitQuery1
 - handleSaveHistory1
```

next state:

```
(re-rendered after executing `await fetch`)

Chat1 (DEAD)                      Chat2 (visible to user)
 - history1                        - history2
 - handleSubmitQuery1 (awaiting)   - handleSubmitQuery2
 - handleSaveHistory1              - handleSaveHistory2
```

now the `fetch` returns in *the old, dead `Chat1` component*

next state:

```
Chat1 (DEAD)                      Chat2 (visible to user)
 - history1                        - history2
 - handleSubmitQuery1              - handleSubmitQuery2
 - handleSaveHistory1 (console!)   - handleSaveHistory2
```

Comment: How can I resolve the issue then, spent whole night on it then my mind stopped working :P